# Jquery does not count correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to book a ticket with a free offer, these are the rules:

- One person can buy 1 or more tickets, but limited to 4
- He can make a minumum offer of 1 euro, but no limit, for tickets. So if he buys 4 tickets the offer will be at least 4 euros.

The check (`validate()`) happens after page loading and on every `change` or `keyup` event. All seems ok when I increase tickets to buy from 1 to 2, the offer increase from 1 to 2, as expected.

**My issue:**
When I leave "ticket" (first input) on 2 and I increase the offer, it does not exceed 9, at 10 it set the input value back to same value that is in the ticket input.

Also, if I hold arrow up to increase number until 50, for example, it's ok.

What's wrong?

My code is:

```js
validate();

$('.input_data').on('change keyup', validate);

function validate() {
  control_tick = $("input[name='ticket']").val();
  if ((control_tick < 1) || (control_tick > 4)) {
    control_tick = 1;
    $("input[name='ticket']").val(control_tick);
  } else {
    $("input[name='ticket']").val(control_tick);
  }

  control_off = $("input[name='offer']").val();

  if (control_tick > control_off) {
    control_off = control_tick;
    $("input[name='offer']").val(control_off);
    console.log('prezzo minore di ticket');
  }
  if (control_off => control_tick) {
    $("input[name='offer']").val(control_off);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Ticket number (max 4):</label><br>
<input class="w3-input w3-center input_data" type="number" name="ticket" value="1" min="1" max="4" step="1">

<label>Offer €:</label>

<input class="w3-input w3-center input_data" type="number" name="offer" value="1" min="1" max="1000" step="1">
```

Comment: Please edit this for spelling and grammar. I'm not asking for perfect english, just something better than this.

Comment: Note that the comparison operator is `>=`, not `=>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause**

When you get the value of a field using `.val()`, that value is always of type `string`. Therefore when you compare the values using `if (control_tick > control_off) {`, you're comparing two **strings**, not two **numbers**. And in the rules of string comparison, `"2"` is considered to be "greater" than `"10"`, because it compares each character one at a time, rather than the whole string, and clearly it regards "2" as greater than "1".

(Regarding holding the up arrow to 50, this will be ok because `"50"` (or rather, `"5"` is greater then `"2"` in string comparisons, just as it is in numeric comparisons. But if you hold it all the way to 100 it'll reset again - I'm sure you can work out why, by now.)

**Solution**

You need to parse your values as numbers before you attempt to compare them. Since these will always be whole numbers, we can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). This will ensure it does a numeric comparison instead.

See the demo below for a working example.

(Note also that removed the last `if` statement - apart from the slight syntax error (`=>` should be `>=`, although it doesn't cause a syntax error because it's valid, (but useless) as an arrow expression) it seemed redundant, because you're just populating the field with the same value you got from it a moment earlier. The `else` after the first `if` is also redundant for the same reason.)

```js
validate();

$('.input_data').on('change keyup', validate);

function validate() {
  control_tick = parseInt($("input[name='ticket']").val());

  if ((control_tick < 1) || (control_tick > 4)) {
    control_tick = 1;
    $("input[name='ticket']").val(control_tick);
  }

  control_off = parseInt($("input[name='offer']").val());

  if (control_tick > control_off) {
    control_off = control_tick;
    $("input[name='offer']").val(control_off);
    console.log('prezzo minore di ticket');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Ticket number (max 4):</label><br>
<input class="w3-input w3-center input_data" type="number" name="ticket" value="1" min="1" max="4" step="1">

<label>Offer €:</label>

<input class="w3-input w3-center input_data" type="number" name="offer" value="1" min="1" max="1000" step="1">
```